# How can I compare the results of two lmRob() models?

Tags: r, regression, lm, confidence-interval, robust

I am looking for a way to compare the results from two `lmRob()` functions statistically.

Here is an explanation of what I am trying to do: My professor wants me to compare the results of two ANCOVAs (one for each sex) in another ANOVA with each other. This is because there seems to be a significant interaction between my predictor and the covariate sex. But based on my assumptions for the ANCOVAs, I need to use a robust model -> `lmRob()`.

Would it be an option for me to check if confidence intervals of the coefficients overlap for a variable between the two `lmRob()` models?

Comment: I don't understand your question, but if you have a `lmRob` model `fit1` and a `lmRob` submodel `fit0` of `fit1`, then you can compare them with `anova(fit0, fit1)`. The overlapping of confidence intervals is not a valid test.

Comment: This is not working in R, it throws an error. Could be because I do not change any variables in the model, just the population (female or male) on which the models are created.